# ZIO IO.collectAll and ZIO.collectAllPar together

Tags: scala, zio

I have a next task, there are N db queries (for example 3 - Seq(10,20,30)) and iterationCount = 4.
I want use ZIO and next: Sequentially execute iterations and inside iterations evaluate effects parallel.

Simplified code looks like this

```
import zio._
import zio.console._

case class Res(iterNum :Int, dataValue :Int)

val execUnpure :(Int,Int) => Res = (iterNum,dataValue) =>
 Res(iterNum, dataValue)

val exec :(Int,Int) => Task[Res] = (iterNum,dataValue) =>
  Task.succeed(Res(iterNum, dataValue))

val evalEffectsParallel: (Int, Seq[Int]) => Task[Seq[Res]] =
  (iterNum, sqLoadConf) =>
    ZIO.collectAllPar(
      sqLoadConf.map(lc => 
        for {
          //here I open NEW db session for this exec.
          tr: Res <- exec(iterNum, lc)
        } yield tr

      )
    )

val seqParallelExec: (Int, Seq[Int]) => Task[Seq[Res]] =
  (iterNum, sqLoadConf) =>
    for {
      sqTestResults: List[Seq[Res]] <-
      IO.collectAll(
        (1 to iterNum).map(thisIter => evalEffectsParallel(thisIter, sqLoadConf))
      )
      r <- Task(sqTestResults.flatten)
    } yield r

val program : Int => Task[Seq[Res]] = iterationCount => 
      for {
            res <- seqParallelExec(iterationCount, Seq(10,20,30))
          } yield res

(new zio.DefaultRuntime {}).unsafeRun(
  for {
    sp <- program(4)
    _  <- putStrLn(s"seqpar = ${sp.toString}")
  } yield ()
)
```

This code works and return 
`seqpar = List(Res(1,10), Res(1,20), Res(1,30), Res(2,10), Res(2,20), Res(2,30), Res(3,10), Res(3,20), Res(3,30))`

But each effect (exec : Task[Res]) execute in parallel.

It looks like IO.collectAll or sqTestResults.flatten not appropriate here.

IN real code, on the place "here I open NEW db session for this exec." I open new jdbc connection to Postgres. When I run this code and monitor active sessions from pg_stat_activity I see that application produce a lot of session, count equal 4*3=12.

But my expectation is to see about 3 sessions for first iteration in single time, and further new 3 sessions and new 3 sessions in next time.

Solution from  Adam Fraser works as expected, but I made simpler it for me.

```
  private val execute: (Int, PgConnectProp, PgLoadConf) => Task[PgTestResult] =
    (iterNum, dbConProps, lc) =>
      (new PgConnection).sess(iterNum,dbConProps).flatMap(thisSess => PgTestExecuter.exec(iterNum, thisSess, lc))

  private val executeSession :(Int, PgConnectProp,  Seq[PgLoadConf]) => Task[Seq[PgTestResult]] =
    (iteration, dbConProps, sqLoadConf) =>
      Task.foreachPar(sqLoadConf)(lc => execute(iteration, dbConProps, lc))

  private val seqparExec: (PgRunProp, PgConnectProp, Seq[PgLoadConf]) => Task[Seq[PgTestResult]] =
    (runProperties, dbConProps, sqLoadConf) =>
      Task.foreach(List.range(1, runProperties.repeat + 1)) {
        iteration => executeSession(iteration, dbConProps, sqLoadConf)
      }
        .map(_.flatten)
```

and results of 3 iterations.

```
 iter : [1] test : [1] pid=[13505] startTs [1575955678690] endTs [1575955678756] 
 iter : [1] test : [4] pid=[13510] startTs [1575955678691] endTs [1575955678883] 
 iter : [1] test : [6] pid=[13508] startTs [1575955678697] endTs [1575955678965] 
 iter : [1] test : [5] pid=[13507] startTs [1575955678697] endTs [1575955679106] 
 iter : [1] test : [2] pid=[13506] startTs [1575955678693] endTs [1575955679208] 
 iter : [1] test : [3] pid=[13509] startTs [1575955678697] endTs [1575955680438] 

iter : [2] test : [1] pid=[13514] startTs [1575955680653] endTs [1575955681291] 
 iter : [2] test : [4] pid=[13517] startTs [1575955681071] endTs [1575955681367] 
 iter : [2] test : [5] pid=[13518] startTs [1575955681071] endTs [1575955681396] 
 iter : [2] test : [6] pid=[13519] startTs [1575955681276] endTs [1575955681484] 
 iter : [2] test : [2] pid=[13515] startTs [1575955681071] endTs [1575955681645] 
 iter : [2] test : [3] pid=[13516] startTs [1575955681106] endTs [1575955682712] 

iter : [3] test : [1] pid=[13521] startTs [1575955682830] endTs [1575955682903] 
 iter : [3] test : [4] pid=[13524] startTs [1575955682819] endTs [1575955682938] 
 iter : [3] test : [6] pid=[13526] startTs [1575955682832] endTs [1575955683137] 
 iter : [3] test : [5] pid=[13525] startTs [1575955682863] endTs [1575955683428] 
 iter : [3] test : [2] pid=[13522] startTs [1575955682816] endTs [1575955683476] 
 iter : [3] test : [3] pid=[13523] startTs [1575955682902] endTs [1575955684056]
```

each first session for this iteration starts after last endTs of previous iteration. But postgres session needs little bit time to close it can make 
sense of global parallel execution. But real it's sequential for iterations and parallel inside.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to flatten the list of results as opposed to the effects. Also, you should consider `bracket` or `Managed` to handle opening and closing your database connections so you don't have to worry about that yourself. I've included an example below.

```scala
import zio._
import zio.console._

object Example extends App {

  final case class Result(iteration: Int, value: Int)

  def execute(iteration: Int, value: Int): URIO[Console, Result] =
    console.putStrLn(s"Executing iteration $iteration, value $value").as(Result(iteration, value))

  def executeSession(iteration: Int, values: List[Int]): URIO[Console, List[Result]] =
    URIO.bracket[Console, Unit, List[Result]](
      console.putStrLn(s"Opening database connection $iteration"),
      _ => console.putStrLn(s"Closing database connection $iteration"),
      _ => URIO.foreachPar(values)(value => execute(iteration, value))
    )

  def executeSessions(iterations: Int, values: List[Int]): URIO[Console, List[Result]] =
    URIO
      .foreach(List.range(1, iterations + 1)) { iteration =>
        executeSession(iteration, values)
      }
      .map(_.flatten)

  def program(n: Int): URIO[Console, List[Result]] =
    executeSessions(n, List(10, 20, 30))

  def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, Int] =
    program(4).as(0)
}
```